# MySQL two tables SELECT and JOIN command

Tags: mysql, join, select

I've seen multiple past questions where they use the JOIN LEFT to fetch data from more than one table but I'm not quite sure on my formatting for my specific command.

This is the SELECT command I need to use

```
SELECT * FROM Horse, Images WHERE Horse.id = '$colname' AND Horse.Image_name = Images.Image_name
```

Can someone help me figure out where the JOIN LEFT would go into this? Or explain how to know where to insert the JOIN LEFT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With LEFT JOIN the query will be like this

```
SELECT * FROM Horse 
LEFT JOIN Images ON Horse.Image_name = Images.Image_name
WHERE Horse.id = "$colname";
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you explain that a bit to me? Does the LEFT JOIN just go between the two table names and then ON would go before the first item thats being compared?

Comment: @LondonO'Connell Yes exactly you got the point, Also I edited the solution and attached an image.

Comment: I know this is a late response, but I have another SQL statement and was curious if you could help me with this one as well. SELECT Images.Image_name, Images.Image_path, Horse.id, Horse.Name, Horse.Breed, Horse.Gender, Horse.Image_name, Horse.Owner FROM Horse, Images WHERE Owner = 'RopinRanch' - there's no comparison so I don't know what kind of JOIN it would be

Comment: Is this statement running fine and giving you the required output?

Comment: It gives me the data, but it repeats it by 195 times (legitly that many times) @Harish

Comment: Ok I understood, The query will be like this `SELECT table_2.Image_name, table_2.Image_path, table_1.id, table_1.Name, table_1.Breed, table_1.Gender, table_1.Image_name, table_1.Owner 
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.horse_id 
FROM table_1, table_2 WHERE table_1.Owner = 'RopinRanch'` If you can share the column names then we can write exact statement.